# How to stop double redirect on https and www in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting

I was using IIS rewrite rules in web.config to do my HTTPS and non-www canonical URI enforcement, but then using Web Deploy became complicated so I switched to ASP.NET Core 6 middleware. Here's my code from Program.cs:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToNonWwwPermanent());
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

For http://example.com and https://www.example.com it works great and there is a single redirect.

But, for http://www.example.com it now implements the non-www rule, then the https rule, so you get two 308 redirects chained together (with IIS I had this with a single redirect).

You can test it here: https://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php

Enter: *http://www.magazedia.com/*

```
http://www.magazedia.com
308 Permanent Redirect
http://magazedia.com/
308 Permanent Redirect
https://magazedia.com/
200 OK
```

This plays havoc with my OCD.

Is there a simple fix or do I need to write a custom redirect that combines both?

**EDIT:**

I also just tried this, but the result is the same (double redirect):

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToNonWwwPermanent().AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent() );
// app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the asp.net core url rewrite middleware also support using the url rewrite rule xml.

You could create a url reiwte xml named `IISUrlRewrite.xml` and like below:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite segment to id querystring" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^iis-rules-rewrite/(.*)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="rewritten?id={R:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Then modify the startup.cs(.net 5) or program.cs(.net 6)

```
       using (StreamReader iisUrlRewriteStreamReader = 
            File.OpenText("IISUrlRewrite.xml")) 
        {
            var options = new RewriteOptions()
                .AddIISUrlRewrite(iisUrlRewriteStreamReader)
            app.UseRewriter(options);
        }
```

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Thank you - this idea does work, in that it uses my IIS rules and gets rid of the double redirect, but with two caveats which are probably easily solvable. This is the code I ended up using to simplify:  app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite( app.Environment.WebRootFileProvider, "IISUrlRewrite.xml") ); -- but I've yet to work out how to put the XML file in the project root, rather than in the wwwroot folder, and secondly, this only uses 301 redirects like my web.config, but I would love to convert this to do 308s instead!

Comment: OK, I solved the 2nd caveat with redirectType="308" in the rewrite rule.

Comment: OK, for the 1st caveat I tried moving the XML file to the project root and changing to app.Environment.ContentRootFileProvider which should have worked, but I figured out why it DOESN'T work. VS doesn't deploy the XML file into the root folder when I do a web deploy. I think the XML file is getting compiled into the binary. I've not figured out how to stop that.

Comment: You could click the xml file and find its property, it contians the copy aways when publish. You could choose that and it will work.

Comment: For some reason I can't get the CopyToOutputDirectory option to work at all. I've tried a hundred different permutations using the UI in VS and changing the .csproj file :(