# In ASP.NET Core how do I read an XML file that is outside the web root?

Tags: asp.net-core

In my previous question the solution to my problem involved having to write an XML configuration file and then read it at startup:
[How to stop double redirect on https and www in ASP.NET Core 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70950634/how-to-stop-double-redirect-on-https-and-www-in-asp-net-core-6)

In Program.cs I ended up with this:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite( app.Environment.WebRootFileProvider, "IISUrlRewrite.xml") );
```

Which works fine if the XML file is in wwwroot. I tried moving the XML file to the Content (Project) Root but nothing I change in the .csproj will cause it to just copy that file over to the server when I do a web deploy. It feels like the XML file is being compiled into the code.

I'd really like the file to live in a "Resources" folder and access it that way somehow.

Is there a way I can do that? Make a folder called Resources and access it through the API somehow? I need to get a StreamReader object to pass to the AddIISUrlRewrite function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's how I got it working. I have my IIS Url Rewrite rules that I took from web.config and I put them in an XML file called IISUrlRewrite.xml. I made a folder off the root of my web application project called Resources, and I put the XML file in there. Then I right-clicked on the file in the Solution Explorer and selected a Build Action of Embedded Resource.

Here are the contents of the XML file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="308" />
            </rule>
            <rule enabled="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="308" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

And this was the code I wrote in Program.cs to make it all work:

```cs
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        Assembly? ExecutingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Stream? ManifestResourceStream = ExecutingAssembly!.GetManifestResourceStream(ExecutingAssembly.GetName().Name + ".Resources.IISUrlRewrite.xml");
        TextReader ResourceTextReader = new StreamReader(ManifestResourceStream!);
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite(ResourceTextReader));
    }
```

Now my HTTP->HTTPS and WWW->Non-WWW redirects all work perfectly on the production server.